# Ensure that loopback root and host are unmounted on shutdown

Tags: linux, shutdown, loop-device, root-filesystem, unmounting

I'm trying to setup a Linux system that runs from an LVM-formatted image file. After some tinkering with the initramfs and boot options I managed to make it up and running by mounting the host file system to `/run/initramfs/host`, `losetup`ing the image to `/dev/loop0` and making sure the kernel and udev detect the LVM (and the root LV) in there. So far so good.

The problem is that when shutting down (or rebooting, or …) the system neither the  root file system nor the host are unmounted properly, because of a chicken-and-egg scenario: the root (or `/oldroot`, as it's referred to by the shutdown script) cannot be unmounted, because `/oldroot/run/initramfs/host` is still mounted, and the host cannot be unmounted, because doing so would make `/oldroot` inaccessible.

Unclean shutdowns aren't the end of the world, because both file systems are journaled, so during the next boot `fsck` simply replays the journals, but obviously clean shutdowns would be better.

So the question is: is it somehow possible to arrange the shutdown sequence (I *can* modify the shutdown script), *or* the bootup sequence (perhaps by moving the host mount point to a different place) so that both file systems can be cleanly unmounted?

Comment: Why `losetup` under `lvm`? Lvm use `dmsetup` wich is a kind of *more featured losetup*.

Comment: See `mount --move`

Comment: @F.Hauri: `losetup`, because it's the first thing I thought of that turns a file into a block device. Also, the chicken-and-egg problem at hand is not really related to LVM, is it?

Comment: Could you tell me where is the shutdown script? I have the same problem, so I need to manage it. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case somebody has the same problem:

All I needed was to move the mount point of the host file system to a place outside the root file system in the shutdown script (that's fine, because it runs in a `tmpfs` pivot root) before any unmounting takes place:

```
mount --move /oldroot/run/initramfs/host /host
```

This allows `/oldroot` to unmount cleanly. The host file system can be then unmounted with a simple

```
umount /host
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining where this shutdown script might be placed? Thanks!

Comment: Please could you explain how to write that shutdown script?

Answer (score 1):

There is some *linux* trick to do this kind of work:

- `mount --move` which let you *swap* filesystem on mount point
- `pivot_root` which work with `chroot` for switch `/` root filesystem

Initialy, the *feature*'s goal was:

1. booting kernel with an `initramdisk` as *root filesystem* (reserving some `RAM` for uncompressed `initrd`).
2. All needed modules and scripts to access *real root device* are initiated in this 1'st boot step. (This could contain network initialisation and network devices mounting)
3. After preparing, checking *real root device* and mounting as a ready root filesytem. Running `pivot_root` (and `chroot`), so after operation, the `ramdisk` will become an *unused ram disk* mounted at `/initrd`.
4. So from there, it is possible to `umount /initrd` and freeing memory.

Have a look at `man mount`  and `man pivot_root`!

Comment: As I don't know your hierarchy and not sure to clearly understand your goal, I can't offer a more detailed solution (than you could find in `man mount` ... and I hate to simply cut'n past from man pages)

Comment: That's okay, you pointed me in the right direction by mentioning `mount --move`.

Comment: Just for my comprehension: Why did you **need** to `umount /old` **before** `umount /old/blah/host` ??

Comment: Because `/old` is actually (a part of) a file stored in `/old/blah/host`.

Answer (score 1):

To mark a filesystem as cleanly unmounted without making the files on it unavailable, remount it as read-only:

```
mount -o remount,ro /mount/point
```

This can be done even if there are files open for reading, running executables, current directories or active mount points on that filesystem. Only files open for writing prevent remounting read-only.